# React Native, values are not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I made a edit screen and trying to update the value of post through navigation v4 by using getParams and set setParams but when I change the old value and click save buttton to save it, it's not updating it and no error is showing either. It's still showing old values. Can someone please help me, below is my code

EditScreen.js

```
class EditScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior="position"
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : 100}
      >
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={this.props.navigation.getParam("image")}
        />

        <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
          <AppTextInput
            value={this.props.navigation.getParam("title")}
            onChangeText={(text) =>
              this.props.navigation.setParams({ title: text })
            }
          />
          <AppTextInput
            value={this.props.navigation.getParam("des")}
            onChangeText={(text) =>
              this.props.navigation.setParams({ des: text })
            }
          />
        </View>
        <AppButton
          text="Save"
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.getParam("onEdit");
            this.props.navigation.goBack();
          }}
        />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
    post: [
      {
        key: "1",
        title: "A Good Boi",
        des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
        image: require("../assets/dog.jpg"),
      },
      {
        key: "2",
        title: "John Cena",
        des: "As you can see, You can't see me!",
        image: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
      },
    ],
  };

  onEdit = (data) => {
    const newPosts = this.state.post.map((item) => {
      if (item.key === data.key) return data;
      else return item;
    });
    this.setState({ post: newPosts, editMode: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Screen style={styles.screen}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.post}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.7}
                onPress={() =>
                  this.props.navigation.navigate("Edit", {
                    image: item.image,
                    title: item.title,
                    des: item.des,
                    onEdit: this.onEdit,
                  })
                }
                style={styles.Edit}
              >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="playlist-edit"
                  color="green"
                  size={35}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Card onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push("Details", item)}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
                <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>
                    {item.title}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.subTitle} numberOfLines={2}>
                    {item.des}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </Card>
            </>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
<AppButton
    text="Save"
    style={styles.button}
    onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.getParam("onEdit")(this.props.navigation.state.params);
        this.props.navigation.goBack();
    }}
/>
```

and:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Edit", {
                    key: item.key,
                    image: item.image,
                    title: item.title,
                    des: item.des,
                    onEdit: this.onEdit,
                  })
```

Comment: hye, you helped me yesterday too... XD that's kind of same task but with navigation this time i'm using the same function but i think it's not getting that function

Comment: Yep, remember you. can you log what ` this.props.navigation.getParam("onEdit")` is

Comment: it's basically the function you tell to do on home screen i'm passing that function with navigation.navigate and receiving it like that

Comment: and on doing console.log it's show `[Function anonymous]`

Comment: oh you need to send the key as well in Home.js, here: `this.props.navigation.navigate("Edit",..` if not the onEdit doesn't know what post to replace in the state

Comment: ok which key should  I send? I already set this.onEdit

Comment: It worked thanks so we need to also send key with item in navigation v4, need to remember and can you tell me why you added `(this.props.navigation.state.params);` in appButton

Comment: so onEdit you need to send the data of the edited post, and that data is stored in the navigation params. Please remember to set the response as accepted :P

Comment: can you help me in my another problem that i'm facing from weeks?

Comment: i can try, let me know what you need

Comment: oh here it is i created a Image picker component and added it to formik but when i add post it's not displaying image and show's `invaild image prop` link is below

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64224190/react-native-invalid-prop-source?noredirect=1#comment113571965_64224190

Comment: i added a comment

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to keep the data in the component state:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 // get the data that you need from navigation params
 const { key, title, ..} = this.props.navigation.state.params
 this.state = {key, title, ..}
}
```

then :

```
  <AppTextInput
    value={this.state.title}
    onChangeText={(text) =>
      this.setState({ title: text })
    }
  />

    <AppButton
      text="Save"
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.getParam("onEdit")(this.state);
        this.props.navigation.goBack();
      }}
    />
```